# call back mechanism in C# .net

Tags: c#

i wanted to know how can we implement call back mechanism in .net, since managed code does not support function pointer

Comment: "managed code does not support function pointer " - erm, yes it does. It's called a delegate = Type-Safe Function Pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this by using `Delegates` and `events`

have a look on http://en.csharp-online.net/Delegates_and_Events%E2%80%94Callback_Methods

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a delegate as shown below

```
delegate void CallBackTest();
CallBackTest callBackTest = new CallBackTest(TestCallBack);
callBackTest.BeginInvoke(task, new AsyncCallback(functionExecuted), null);


void TestCallBack()
{ }

private void functionExecuted(IAsyncResult result)
{
    try
    {
        callBackTest.EndInvoke(result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //FileWriter.LogException(ex);
    }
}
```